# Powering Raspberry Pi Zero W with Lipo without USB connection

Tags: power, wireless, pi-zero-w

I am working on a wireless project that I wanted to run on battery. I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W and an Adafruit PowerBoost 1000C. How would I connect this using some wires as a usb cable would be too bulky for my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Raspberry PI Zero has no protection circuit on the input, therefore it is safe to power directly to GPIO Header Pins (physical pin number) `2,4` aka `5V`. More accurately, as safe as using USB Connector for power.

The USB Connector is directly connected to that `5V` "net" as shown in these [schematic excerpts](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_ZeroW_1p1_reduced.pdf)

[image]

[image]

However, you must make sure there is no chance someone will power from USB at the same time or there is a dangerous possibility. I suggest you desolder the USB connector before deploying it permanently.

For Information on the Protection Circuit in Pi1/2/3 see my other answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73130/71180)